# Rails unpredictable behaviour on has_many with foreign_key and primary_key changed options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I faced with unpredictable behaviour of `has_many` association on fetching `ids` of associated objects. The models:

```
class Dealer < AR::Base
  # attributes :id, :dk_id and so on
  with_options class_name: 'Campaign', primary_key: :dk_id, foreign_key: :dk_specific_id do |assoc|
    assoc.has_many :campaigns
  end
end

class Campaign
  # attributes :id, :dk_specific_id and so on
end
```

I want to fetch 'campaign_ids' for `dealer`. It returns an error. I can't understand why.

```
dealer = Dealer.first
dealer.campaigns # => return a list of campaigns to me
dealer.campaign_ids # => exception
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column campaigns.dk_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "campaigns".dk_id FROM "camp...
               ^
: SELECT "campaigns".dk_id FROM "campaigns" WHERE "campaigns"."dk_specific_id" = $1
```

Please help me to understand how to make this method work. I can't understand why this method asking `campaigns` table about `dk_id`, because it should ask it just about `id`, isn't it?

**UPDATED**

`dk_id` is the primary key, which value can be something like `abc1`. So, campaigns for this dealer having `dk_specific_id=abc1`

Comment: I'm confused about the necessity to use `with_options`... why not just `has_many :campaigns, foreign_key: "dk_specific_id"`?

Comment: just remove the `primary_key` option from your `Dealer` model

Comment: try making `primary_key: "dk_id"` string.

Comment: `:primary_key` means the primary key of `Campaigns` to which your table `Dealers` refers, should `id` by default. `:foreign_key` is the attribute of `Dealers` from where you take the `Campaigns` ID.

Comment: @LannyBose there is a lot of other stuff inside `with_options` block

Comment: @YuryLebedev I updated the question